# Frame bounding boxes within resolution gate

Tags: python, maya, bounding-box

I am trying to write a turntable script in which it will automatically fits all my objects(bounding box) within the frame of my resolution gate which is HD 1080 (1920x1080)

```
test = cmds.select('MODELS*')
mel.eval('FrameSelectedInAllViews')
cmds.setAttr('TT_CAM.cameraScale', 1)
```

As I have quite a few, is my above code the correct way to script for bounding boxes?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but are you looking for a way to frame all your objects automatically with the camera? Have you tried pressing the F key? (frame)

Comment: Yes I did. But for some reasons, some of my models are being 'chopped-off' I am guessing it is the bounding box problem

Comment: Bumping up the camera scale value will of course appear as if it's zooming out more, however I'm curious why you just don't zoom out manually as it's most probably faster than scripting this?

Comment: But is there anyway not to change any camera values? By the way I chanced upon pymel.core.datatypes.BoundingBox? Any chances this will help me?

Comment: I provided you a solution below which doesn't actually change any camera values. Using the boundingbox attributes may help you get the size of the overall selection, but translating that to a camera as positional values is a whole other ball game, may I ask what it is you're actually trying to do? And what for? There may be another approach.

Comment: Hi I tried your method still it is cutting away some of my stuff, the same problem as I have first stated where no human model leg and head is out of the resolution gate... What I am trying to do is that I want all my items in my bounding box to be framed and seen in my viewport within the resolution ( not chopped off)  and without changing the camera shape values ( focal length, camera scale etc _-  my bad earlier that I did not explain properly on not changing the camera attributes) however the translation and rotation values of camera can be tweaked

Comment: I'm confused as to why you just don't zoom out though?

Comment: Im trying to make it as an automated script without the need for users to zoom out...

Comment: I have changed my answer for you, this does automatically fill to the selection's bounding box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could only think of creating temporary locators, that fill the bounding box of the selected objects, then framing those locators, this works fine so far from what I've tested.

I've included comments in the script below:

```
from pymel.core import *

select("MODELS*")

## Gather our world bounding box and store it in a variable called b
b = general.exactWorldBoundingBox()

## b now contains min and max XYZ world coords
## Name our temporary locators

locName = "tempLoc"
## Create a locator at each min and max point to form a fake bounding box

positions = [[0,1,2], [0,4,2], [0,4,5], [3,4,5], [3,1,5], [3,4,2], [3,1,2], [0,1,5]]

## Create the locators 
for position in positions:
    print position
    spaceLocator(p=(b[position[0]],b[position[1]],b[position[2]]), name=locName)

## Once we create the locators, frame locators, delete

tempLocators = select("tempLoc*", r=1)
runtime.FrameSelectedInAllViews()
delete()
```

Comment: Funnily enough, it seems to work for my other bounding boxes as long as they do not contain a humanoid figure in them... But still there are a small chance that it did not work for some of my building models

Comment: Are they still named the same? Are they all starting with MODELS ?

Comment: ya... All stuff are 'MODELS_character_..' or 'MODELS_item_...' etc...
It turns out that if one of the building is pretty big as well, and it 'chopped' off some in the top and bottom as well, though not as much as the human models

Comment: hmm, this is the only way that I can think of that will be closer to what you're after, unfortunately the perspective of the camera that you're using will also come into play, which is a variable where unless your cameras are in the exact same position in every scene, is not going to ever be 100%, I hope this is closer to what you're after and if it is, be sure to mark it as the answer :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out. Actually your code does helps me. One way I have managed to get my stuff framed within the resolution gate is to create a plane as the base (taking the highest height value of the BBox(s)).. I know this is rather ineffective/stupid? but still, it works for me, for now.... :)

Comment: Hey, whatever works, works, if it's a quick solution for something simple, use it.

Comment: Sorry I know this is a bit late, but could someone explains to me `p=(b[0], b[1], b[2])`? I'm guessing it is the position (x,y,z) but I thinking there's more to it right?

Comment: `general.exactWorldBoundingBox()` returns both min and max XYZ world coordinates. So from this information, I'm able to use this list of data by saving it in `b`, using these position values to position the locators at vector coordinates to form our locator 'bounding box'. It is just positional values, but we're getting them from an array, not just manual input.